# Reference a cell using IF inside VLOOKUP on Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I want to perform a vlookup with an if statement inside. I currently have

`=LOOKUP("Metallic Gold Flash Tattoo Arabic",A:A,IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), E)))<0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), C)),0)`

I want to sum up all the units of that product type in column A, however I only want to sum up the ones that have been sold and not bought. Column C is units and E is price. Sold are positive and negative are bought.

I am using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to sum column C (quantity of units) when the description matches in column A and col E is > 0

Try using `SUMIFS` - that should work in both excel and google sheets, i.e.

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Metallic Gold Flash Tattoo Arabic",E:E,">0")`

....or do you want to get the total cost price of those units (Col C multiplied by E for the relevant rows)?

For that you can use this formula in google sheets

`=sum(filter(C:C*E:E,E:E>0,A:A="Metallic Gold Flash Tattoo Arabic"))`

Comment: Was just about to post a `SUMPRODUCT` answer, but it seems `SUMIFS` work well enough also

Comment: Yes, I think `SUMPRODUCT` is a good option too, especially if you do want to multiply two columns which you can't do with `SUMIFS`

Comment: is it possible to use regular expression "Metallic Gold Flash Tattoo Arabic*" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a query:

```
=QUERY(A:E, "SELECT A, SUM(E) WHERE A = 'Metallic Gold Flash Tattoo Arabic' AND C > 0", 1)
```

I'm assuming that column C contains the positive and negative values indicating sold and bought.